# Express forms plaintext email template

Tags: plugins, solspace, plugin-expressforms

Is there any way to send a plaintext email with the "express forms" plugin? Can't seem to find a way to define it, and no information about it in the documentation.

The mail should be in plain text, not HTML formatted. But it has an attachment. Any help very much appreciated!